# Умный фильтр для каталога по брендам

Tags: php, битрикс

В интернет магазине у каждого товара есть свойство Brand, которое хранит название бренда. Также создан инфоблок с брендами, в котором хранится название бренда и его символьный код.

Необходимо было сделать страницу которая выводит все товары текущего бренда, а также все товары бренда текущей категории, и для этих страниц добавить умный фильтр. Но умный фильтр работает только по разделам и так сделать не получилось.

Пробовал сделать костыль, который перед запуском компонента умного фильтра напрямую с массив сессии добавляет значения полей фильтра таким кодом

```
$param_name = 'arrFilter_'.$prop_id.'_'. abs( crc32( htmlspecialcharsbx( $prop_value ) ) );
```

Где $prop_id - id свойства Brand, а pro_value соответственно его значение.

```
$_SESSION['arrFilter'][$param_name] = 'Y'
```

И естественно само свойство бренд из шаблона фильтра убрали

Это должно было работать, если включить сохранение фильтра в сессии. Но т.к. свойство вводилось вручную значения немного разные, например отличались регистром и хеш не подходил.

Как можно заставить умный фильтр фильтровать не по разделам, а по брендам?

Comment: А свойству Brand в настройках не судьба поставить галочку "Использовать в умном фильтре"? Это в настройках свойства в настройках инфоблока делается. Читайте хоть иногда документацию.

Comment: @NikolajSarry . Не до конца понял, что вы имеете в виду. Мне нужно не использовать бренд в фильтре, а сделать так чтобы фильтр работал с товарами объединенными брендом также, как и с разделом инфоблока. Не думаю что здесь поможет простое включение свойства в фильтр.

Comment: Теперь стало понятнее. Сейчас дам ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Для того чтобы реализовать такой отбор Вам нужно воспользоваться полем `"FILTER_NAME"` компонента в которое необходимо передать фильтр отбора записей.
Пример как такое сделать можете посмотреть [здесь](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=5186&), [здесь](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/content/iblock/components_2/news/news_list.php), [здесь](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/filters/date.php) и [здесь](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=2683)

В Вашем случае примерный вид для фильтрации будет такой:

```
<?php
global $arBrandFilter;
$arBrandFilter = array(
    "PROPERTY_CODE" => VALUE,
);
?>
```

Это пример фильтра.

Вы можете расширять этот массив в зависимости от условий. Для фильтрации по свойствам используйте описание свойства в формате `PROPERTY_CODE => array(//значения которые принимает свойство)`. При переходе на страницу с товарами определенного бренда вам остается только определить что это за бренд, чтобы сформировать фильтр по конкретному бренду.

Теперь переменную с фильтром передаете в код вызова компонента отображения товара `FILTER_NAME`:
    ...
    "FILTER_NAME" => $arBrandFilter
    ...

Важно: код определяющий переменную фильтра должен располагаться в том же месте, что и вызов компонента вывода списка товаров и перед вызовом компонента.